# PHP-CPP not getting installed on ubuntu running PHP 7

Tags: php, compiling

After cloning [PHP-CPP](http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/install) from [here](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP), running command make always outputs this error:

php-config: not found In file included from zend/inivalue.cpp:8:0: zend/includes.h:40:17: fatal error: php.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

I don't know why `#include <php.h>` is failing to load php.h. Something really weird since I have php7 installed and runs smoothly on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem was I didn't have the php 7 dev packages on my machine. And since php.h comes within that package I had to install it.

I just installed those and everything works as expected.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

Hope this helps anyone in future days.